# Chef Error while bootstrapping. Authorization Error: (HTTP 403)

Tags: chef-infra

I recreated a node with the same name. I've run into this error setting up a node and bootstrapping it:

```
 Starting Chef Client, version 11.16.4
 [2014-11-24T18:51:13+00:00] INFO: *** Chef 11.16.4 ***
 [2014-11-24T18:51:13+00:00] INFO: Chef-client pid: 4540
 Creating a new client identity for node1 using the validator key.
 [2014-11-24T18:51:15+00:00] INFO: Client key /etc/chef/client.pem is not present - registering
 [2014-11-24T18:51:16+00:00] INFO: HTTP Request Returned 409 Conflict: Client already exists
 [2014-11-24T18:51:16+00:00] INFO: HTTP Request Returned 403 Forbidden: error

 ================================================================================
 Chef encountered an error attempting to create the client "node1"
 ================================================================================


 Authorization Error:
 --------------------
 Your validation client is not authorized to create the client for this node (HTTP 403).



 Possible Causes:
 ----------------
 * There may already be a client named "node1"

 * Your validation client (chef-validator) may have misconfigured authorization permissions.
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

In this situation I did not delete the client. The node was recreated with the same name so the node and client both needed to be deleted. Here are the commands to do so.

```
knife node delete <node-name>
knife client delete <node-name>
```

In the above situation it must be:

```
knife node delete node1
knife client delete node1
```

Comment: I ran the command but I got a warning saying "No knife configuration file found". So I changed directory to /etc/chef where I had knife.rb and it solved the problem for me.